# how to add Strike Through functionality on a number in c#

Tags: asp.net

I am showing both discounted price and original price.
but i want to show strike line through original price in c#.how can we do this

Answer (score 4):

Use some css?

```
.originalPrice {text-decoration: line-through;}

<span class="originalPrice">49.99</span>
```